# Loading Firebase Backup Data into BigQuery

Tags: android, json, firebase, google-bigquery

I am trying to load the following JSON Collection from Firebase from my mahjong game into BigQuery for analysis.  This game has about 30K games per day, and I want to do some analysis of the game results. i.e. to determine how successful players behave and provide advice around strategy for playing Mahjong.

The JSON Collection looks like this:

```
- app-id-9999999999
  - games
    - GamerID: TallDingo31118 
      - GameDateTimeStamp: 170731065722722
          discardPlayer: 3
          handle: "TallDingo31118"
          level: 6
          roundNo: 12
          selfDrawn: false
          winningAmount: 288
          winningLevel: 10
          winningPlayer: 0
          winningTiles: "C1C1C1C2C2C2GDGDGDC3C3NWNWNW"
```

The JSON Backup generated looks like this:

```
{"games":
 {"000177811614":
  {"170731065722722":
{"concealed":false,"discardPlayer":3,"level":6,"roundNo":0,"selfDrawn":false,"winningAmount":288,"winningLevel":10,"winningPlayer":1,
 "winningTiles":"C1C1C1C2C2C2GDGDGDC3C3NWNWNW"}},...
```

I am using the automated backup capability in Firebase following this documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/backups

I am using the JSON load capability in BigQuery using this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#loading_json_files

I am stuck with the following error when I generate the load job:

```
Errors:
2017-08-10T02:05:48Z_app-id-999999999.json.gz: Failed to parse JSON: Closing quote expected in string; Could not parse value; Could not parse value; Could not parse value (error code: invalid)
Job ID  app-id-99999999: bquijob_999999_999999999
Creation Time   Aug 15, 2017, 7:18:18 PM
Start Time  Aug 15, 2017, 7:18:19 PM
End Time    Aug 15, 2017, 7:18:36 PM
Destination Table   app-id-99999999999:MahjongGames.Games
Write Preference    Write if empty
Source Format   JSON (Newline Delimited)
Source URI  gs://app-id-999999999-backups/2017-08-10T02:05:48Z-app-id-99999999999_data.json.gz (Open in GCS)
Autodetect Schema   true
```

This looks to me like the JSON format supplied by Firebase is not compatible with the BigQuery JSON parser.

I have tried to post a bug with BigQuery, but they referred me to the Firebase team, who say that it should work and pointed me to the documentation, which I have already followed without success.

This is an advertised feature of Firebase, and should work out-of-the-box.  Has anyone got this to work?

Comment: Is the issue that the JSON is not newline-delimited?

Comment: Great catch @ElliottBrossard. It makes sense that database backups are single-line to save space. If BigQuery import requires newlines, that'd mean the formats are incompatible. The solution in that case would be to `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(backup), null, "")`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and suggestion.  :)   How and/or where can I script this conversion in BigQuery.  Sorry, I am good with FireBase but new to BigQuery.